# "client denied by server configuration" with "AllowOverride All"

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, virtual-machine

I've installed CentOS 6.3 with Apache 2.2 on a VM. I'm trying to set up a LAMP stack with these VirtualHosts:

- `localhost` loads the path `/var/www/html/`
- `lcl.mydomain.com` loads the path `/var/www/html/dev_lcl/`

In `httpd.conf` I added:

```
NameVirtualHost XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80
```

Then I added the `virtualhosts.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "/var/www/html/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log_localhost
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log_localhost "combined"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev_lcl/
    ServerName lcl.mydomain.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html/dev_lcl/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log_dev_lcl
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log_dev_lcl "combined"
</VirtualHost>
```

This gives me the error:

> client denied by server configuration

When I remove `AllowOverride All` both `ServerNames` load, but `mod_rewrite` doesn't work and I need it. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why is the same virtual hostname being used twice....

Comment: As in "VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80"? I understood that that was how to set up multiple VirtualHosts on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I had added to the `.htaccess` file:

```
order deny,allow
allow from XXX.XX.
```

This was causing the problem. Once I removed that it worked fine.